# Creating DIVs in JS and adding Attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I need help with my exercise. Baisically, I want to make a card game. And here is part of my code which should create new divs depends on how many elements I have in my ident array. And this part is ok. Next I want to add IDs to created divs.

I was trying to send content of cont to the other function that would only add the IDs from special array with a loop, but it doesn't work very well.

So I've made a for loop that adds IDs after creating divs. But DIVs appears after the CSS property - first what I can see after clicking button is a border and then divs.

How can I make it with and outern function?

```js
var addButton = document.getElementById('button');
var addButton2 = document.getElementById('button2');
var obrazy = [
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqmjk550o35pvna/coin.jpg?raw=1",
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqmjk550o35pvna/coin.jpg?raw=1",
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqmjk550o35pvna/mario-white.jpg?raw=1",
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqmjk550o35pvna/mario-white.jpg?raw=1",
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqmjk550o35pvna/mush.jpg?raw=1",
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqmjk550o35pvna/mush.jpg?raw=1",
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqmjk550o35pvna/plant.jpg?raw=1",
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqmjk550o35pvna/plant.jpg?raw=1"
];
var ident = [
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  "four",
  "five",
  "six",
  "seven",
  "eight"
];

var output ='';
addButton.onclick = function Loaded(){
  for(var i =0; i<ident.length; i++){
    output += '<div  onclick="memoryFlipCard(this)"></div>'; 
  }
  // document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].setAttribute("class", "democlass");
  var cont = document.getElementById("card_container");
  cont.innerHTML = output;
  
  for(var z=0; z<ident.length;z++){
    cont.childNodes[z].id = ident[z];
  }
  
}
```

```css
body{background-color: white;}
#card_container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  padding: 5px;
  
}

div#card_container > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqmjk550o35pvna/bg.png?raw=1");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 3px;
  float: left;
}

#button {
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding:3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: none;
}

#button2 {
  width: 70px;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#one {
  border: 4px solid red;
}

#four {
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="card_container">
 
</div> 
<button id="button">Add DIVs</button>
<button id="button2">Add IDs</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it :P
Is it ok, now?

```js
addButton2.onclick = function() {
  **var x = document.getElementById("card_container");**
     for(var z=0; z<ident.length;z++){
    x.childNodes[z].id = ident[z];
  }
 };
```